# My code is showing segmentation fault error for three-digit number input

Tags: c++, recursion

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std ;


string keypad[] =
    {
        {""}, {""},       
        { "abc" },
        { "def" },
        { "ghi" },
        { "jkl" },
        { "mno"},
        { "pqrs"},
        { "tuv" },
        { "wxyz"}
    };

int reversDigits(int num)
{
    int rev_num = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        rev_num = rev_num * 10 + num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    return rev_num;
}
int sub( string input , int digit , string output[] ){
    if(input.empty()) {
        output[0] = "";
        return 1;
    }
    string temp = input.substr(1);
    int smallOutputSize = sub( temp , digit , output );

    for( int i = 0; i < smallOutputSize ;i ++){
        output[ i + smallOutputSize ] = input[0] + output[i] ;
    }


    return 2*smallOutputSize;

}


int main(){int N;
    cin >> N ;
    N = reversDigits( N );
    string* output = new string[100];
    string input ;
    int Digit = 0;
    while ( N > 1) {
        input = input + keypad[N%10];
        N=N/10;
        Digit++;
    }
    
    cout << input << endl ;
    int s = sub(input , Digit ,  output );
    cout << s;
    
    for( int i = 0 ; i < s ; i++){
        if ( output[i].size() == Digit   ) cout << output[i] << endl;
    }
    
}
```

This is the question :
Problem Statement: Return Keypad - String
Problem Level: HARD
Problem Description:
Given an integer n, using phone keypad find out all the possible strings that can be made using digits of input n.
Return empty string for numbers 0 and 1.
Note : 1. The order of strings are not important.
2. Input and output has already been managed for you. You just have to populate the output array and return the count of elements populated in the output array.
Input Format :
Integer n

Output Format :
All possible strings in different lines

Constraints :
1 <= n <= 10^6

Sample Input:
23

Sample Output:
ad
ae
af
bd
be
bf
cd
ce
cf

actually, for a three-digit number, this coding is showing segmentation fault.
I tried to see the solution but can't understand it.

Comment: We don't need the full problem statement and full code. We need just a [mre] and a statement of which line in the example triggers the segmentation fault and of what the values of your variables are at that point. When making a [mre], keep in mind that the goal is to preserve the crash; your desired functionality can be trashed (since you don't get it anyway with a crash happening). Eliminate steps that are not needed to reproduce the crash. For example, user input can usually be replaced by fixed values.

Comment: I have the feeling this one is considered "hard", because no one knows what it's asking for. This is a common error in coding challenge problems.

Comment: It's hard to tell without a line number and the input / values in memory that caused the bug. I'd recommend stepping through your code with a debugger to get that kind of information. One thing you can try is replacing `string *output` with `vector<string>` since it's mainly the only thing  being indexed in your program (segmentation faults are often indices out of bounds).

Comment: I expect `i + smallOutputSize` ends up being more than `100`, I think your algorithm produces many more outputs than it should. Note that with the constraint of `n` being up to `10^6` the worst case input of `999999` produces `4^6` or `4096` outputs